# Is it possible to work at the same time in Excel Online (Office 365) and in a local Excel file opened from OneDrive folder?

Tags: microsoft-office, onedrive, office365

I'm trying to figure out how Microsoft does the syncing between Ofice Online and local One Drive files.

I've tried a couple of scenarios, and so far it seems it sync properly only if not opened simultaneously.

Is this the case?

Thanks

Comment: I believe with Office 2016, this is a new feature where users can simultaneously edit. What version of the office suite are you using?

Comment: @InterLinked Office 2016 for Mac. Maybe it's the Mac version that doesn't have that feature